# Return false on parent only

Tags: jquery, html

I am using return false to stop a parent link firing. The parent link is used to open the dropdown.

The problem I have is this return false is also setting return false for the children in the dropdown.

How can I set only the parent link to false, and all the children links to true?

jQuery:

```
$('#account').on('click', function() {
    $('#account-options').fadeIn('slow'); 
    $(document).one('click', function() { 
        $("#account-options").fadeOut('slow'); 
    });
    return false;
});

$("#account-options").on('click', function() { 
    return false; 
});
```

HTML:

```
<li id="account"><a href="/account">Your Account</a>
    <ul id="account-options">
        <li><a href="">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into event propagation. When you click on one of the `<a>` elements in `#account-options` it bubbles up to `#account-options`, executing its click event handler, then in turn up to `#account`, executing its event handler, both of which prevent the default behaviour of the event (in this case, following the link). You need to stop the event propagation at the `<a>` level:

```
$('#account-options a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4NCF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#account-options>li").on('click', function() { 
    return true; 
});
```

Greetings,